# EPUB limits IMG behavior inside TABLE

Tags: image, html-table, epub

In an EPUB document, if one places an IMG element, the iPad iBook reader provides a scaled photo on the reading page, and if the user touches the photo, the reader then provides a full screen display of the photo.

But if one places two IMG elements inside a TABLE, in the context of my product because I am showing "then" and "now" photos, the reader appears unwilling to respond to touches and provide a full screen display of either photo.

I had developed an Objective-C iOS version of this product but was then required by Apple to convert to EPUB. Using the real estate of the iPad to full efficiency under Objective-C iOS is not a problem; getting anything like the same results using HTML5 and within the constraints of the iPad iBook EPUB reader functionality, which is a crippled browser, is a nasty problem.